# Angularjs page and server in two differents servers

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible or good practice to separate the static web server using angularjs and the restful server?

Comment: Yes, it's possible but you should implement https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS in both domain or using, but I don't like very much, JSNOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short:

- possible: yes.
- good practice: it depends

Long version

**Possible:** You only have to be aware of the same origin policy of the browsers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy. But this can be handled - for exapmle - by a proxy or the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header.

**Best praxis:** It depends for example on your deploy strategy. If you seperate the static server and the restful server you may deploy a new version to the restful sever without changing the static web server. But if your frontend and your backend are strong linked, there is no need to do that. I would always recomend the separation if the rest api is only an adon to your application server and the application server has a lot mor functionality then the rest api.

Another advantage is that you can configure the different servers more easily for special needs. like caching strategy or loadbalancing.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your development and deployment setup. If the AngularJs and the Rest service are independently developed and deployed, it might make sense to have them on different servers. The static stuff could just be deployed on e.g. an apache server, while the rest webservice needs an application server.

Because of the Same Origin Policy I would strongly suggest though to configure the servers to look like the same domain from the outside, e.g. with a load balancer.